# How can I make a multiline TextField in Flutter that does NOT wrap?

Tags: flutter, textfield, multiline

`TextField(keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline, maxLines:null)`

makes a multiline TextField that DOES wrap.

How can I make one that does NOT wrap but still adds a newline on RETURN/ENTER key ?

Answer (score 0):

provide a minLine attrubuite to the constructor

```dart
TextFormField(
       minLines: 1,
       maxLines: 3,
 )
```

will be one line initially then will expand as the user types words in it

Comment: Thank you, @ahmed, but with this, the lines still DO wrap. As I said, I want them NOT to wrap, and only add a newline on RETURN/ENTER.